# Combination of foreign keys and pre-defined values as choices for Django model field

Tags: django, django-models

A `ForeignKey` field in one of models stores reference to another model where different versions of `terms and conditions` documents are stored.

```
class Venue(models.Model):
    tc = models.ForeignKey(
    'my_app.TC',
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    help_text=_('Version of tc used by this venue')
)
```

This way every `Venue` can select one of versions of `tc` that suits their needs.

Records in `TC` table are added frequently so if given `Venue` wants to use latest version of document someone needs to manually update it via `django admin`. This is a poorly thought out solution  because there are dozens of `Venue` records in database and they all have different approaches to `tc` usage:

- Some venues want `tc` to be updated automatically to latest version
- Some want/need to bump up their `tc` version manually
- Some venues do not use `tc` at all

---

The goal that needs to be achieved is having 2 extra default options for each `Venue`:

```
1. ---- (blank: venue does not use any `tc`)
2. Latest (venue automatically uses latest version of `tc` available`
```

And unspecified number of available `tc` options (for example foreign keys to `TC` model)

```
1. v1.0.0
2. v2.1.0
3. ...
```

In this case `Latest` is not a relation to `TC` object.
So list of choices for `tc` field in `django admin` can look something like this:

```
- ---- (blank)
- Latest (literally option is named this was, not latest added `tc` object`)
- v1.0.0
- v2.1.0
- ... (other `tc` objects follow down the list)
```

---

That way `Venue` that has selected `Latest` option will automatically be using latest added version of `TC` (handling of this is out of the scope of this question). `Venue` that has selected some specific version of `TC` will stay with it until someone changes it manually.

Is there a way of providing default values to `ForeignKey` field OR using foreign keys as options in `choices` for `CharField`?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to create a custom field, but I think that would be too much of a hassle. The best way to go about this would be to create two fields, a ForeignKey, and a simple flag that determines whether to get a the latest tc or not. 
You can then define a custom property to get the correct TC.

To allow blank ForeignKey fields, just set `null` and `blank` to True.

Something like this:

```
class Venue(models.Model):

     _tc = models.ForeignKey(
          'my_app.TC',
          on_delete=models.CASCADE,
          help_text=_('Version of tc used by this venue'),
          null = True, blank = True
      )

     use_latest_tc = models.BooleanField(default=False)

     @property
     def tc(self):
         if self.use_latest_tc:
              return TC.objects.latest()
         return self._tc
```

Depending on where you change this value, you could write custom JS for your form that hides the ForeignKeyField when use latest is enabled.

The following is untested, but could possibly work. By also creating a setter for tc, you might be able to create a Form with field 'tc' and possible values:

```
@tc.setter
def tc(self, value):
    if value == 'latest':
        self.use_latest_tc = True
        self._tc = True
    else:
        self.use_latest_tc = False
        self._tc = value
```

Comment: That field + flag approach is what I also thought about but I thought maybe there’s a way to do it “right”

Comment: As far as I'm aware, this is the cleanest method.